# HTTP Requests (Python + VBA)

Tags: python, vba, server

can anyone guide me in the right direction when it comes to http requests with python? What I'm after is a Excel-VBA add-in which will track which workbooks the user opens and when etc. While that's already done, I would now like to get the information to a database.

For that purpose I can imagine running a very simple Python server which would be used to store the information. The question thus is, how do I set up a simple http server so that VBA can post a simple string which then gets stored?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks chf! I went ahead and followed your advice - I replaced flask with django though as I had some brief experience with that. I've got my first API ever created now but can't post using the VBA code you posted. I can do httpie like so: "http POST http:/127.0.0.1 name="somename" workbookname="someworkbook".

```
Sub TestFramework()

Dim newClient As New WebClient
Dim newRequest As New WebRequest
Dim Response As WebResponse

newClient.BaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/"

newRequest.Method = HttpPost

newRequest.Format = WebFormat.plaintext
newRequest.AddBodyParameter "name", "somename"
newRequest.AddBodyParameter "workbook_name", "Sheet1"

Set Response = newClient.Execute(newRequest)

End Sub
```

Any chance you might point me to the right way?

> RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
>   [03/Aug/2016 20:13:18] "POST /api/create HTTP/1.1" 500 60534

Edit2: nevermind, got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice project!
You can use [Flask](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the Python part to build a small REST Api and for the VBA part you can use [VBA-WEB](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) to consume that API.

Both Flask than VBA-WEB are very well documented with a lot of examples. 
I use VBA-WEB in a lot of small "SAK" (swiss army knife) utilities in Excel and it's very useful and powerful. 
For some rest apis with json output Flask is a nice tool to use.